# Using node values in a custom token

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to create a custom token using the [Custom Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) module. The token should use (and modify) a node field value, but it not returning any value.

I set the token to need node data and I am using the following code.

```
print ($variables['my_custom_field_name']);
```

How do I access field values within a custom token?

Comment: Did you refer to the docs and APIs regarding custom tokens and how it works?

Comment: This is the custom token module.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but Drupal 7 and 8 have a hook_token_info hook that let you define custom tokens and how they are populated: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7.x

Comment: (Click the link to the module)
I referred to this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2488662. My issue isn't getting the token to display (if I print 'hello world') it works. My issue is getting node field values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating custom tokens for nodes is fairly straightforward, Drupal provides core hooks to define your own. Here is an example from a project I just completed in a small custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_token_info() {
  $info['tokens']['node']['custom_year'] = array(
    'name' => t('Year Field Value'),
    'description' => t('Value from the year field.')
  );

  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function MYMODULE_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = [];

  if ($type == 'node' && !empty($data['node']) && array_key_exists('custom_year', $tokens)) {
    $replacements['[node:custom_year]'] = $data['node']->field_custom_year[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

Where `field_custom_year` is the machine name of your field. This token provides the field value for me and is used in a Pathauto alias token chain. *Most* fields store their data in a `value` column, but not all of them do (like a Date field, or custom fields using country codes, or postal address, or years etc). `[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` won't work in that case, you would need to replace `'value'` with the right name of the column.

Since you are using the Countries module and it stores the field value in a column called `iso2`, then your replacement line would have to be:

`$replacements['[node:custom_token]'] = $data['node']-> field_prgm_country[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['iso2'];`

See:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7.x
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7.x

**Edit**

I assumed you were using this token somewhere where replacement would be otherwise automatic (like a Pathauto alias).

If you are using it in a field, like a Body field (WYSIWYG or plain text), you will need to do the replacing yourself. Drupal does not know you have tokens needing to be replaced, it just assumes its a regular string.

Here is an example of replacing a longtext (body) field tokens with what their values should be:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node().
 * @param $variables
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {  
  if (!empty($variables['node']->field_myfield_name)) {
    $variables['replaced_text'] = token_replace($variables['node']->field_myfield_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], ['node' => $variables['node']]);
  }
}
```

Note that I am not entire sure this example above is 100% accurate in your case, but calling `token_replace(...)` will cause any valid token string found in that fields value to be replaced, which you could then use a debugger within `hook_tokens` above to see whats going on. You'd then have to use that new variable in your node template, or overwrite the fields original value (don't know the full syntax off the top of my head here, sorry).

Alternatively, you could look at [Token Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert) or [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) to aid you here, but both seem to have reported issues of it not working correctly (hence the code first approach here, plus teaches you a little bit about common hooks, extensions, and adding functionality in Drupal).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work but I am having trouble getting the data I need. How can print that $data['node'] array as to see exactly what is availible?

Comment: Is it Drupal 7 or 8? In either case you can use a debugger, xdebug or Devel, and dump $data and look at it.

Comment: This is D7.
Ive tried vardump/kpr( $data['node'] ) and kpr( $data ) in my theme template and neither provide the expected results (just a random string and one letter)

Comment: That won’t work - you’d need to dump it within hook_tokens which is when any token string in use is being replaced (where $data is scoped - it won’t just exist in a theme template). Is anything telling your field to do a token_replace?

Comment: I updated the answer with an edit about `token_replace`.

Comment: I used the code from your answer. It works in pathauto but the problem is I can't access the specific field data I need. `  $replacements`['[node:custom_year]'] =  field_prgm_country[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['iso2'];` works but `$replacements['[node:custom_year]'] =  field_prgm_country[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];`doesn't.

Comment: Gotcha - is this a custom field? Not all fields store their data in a `value` column. In fact, I rewrote the code in my answer to be more generic and use `value`, when in reality, it actually would be `year` for me - but since that is an extreme edge case, I changed it to `value` because thats what 99% of fields store data as. So yes, if your field value column is `iso2`, thats what you should use - you can verify that by looking at the database table for that field and what column the data is stored in.

Comment: It's Countries module, so there is a variety of data associated with the country (full name, continent, language)
Is the easiest way to sort through the data direct in the database?

Comment: Here is my actual code used, using `year` : https://gist.github.com/kevinquillen/f2522d8f3dfe37b6a6c95b6f0c99c743 - so yes, in your case you would use `iso2` and other columns that store data that are currently unsupported. However, using hook_token_info, you can keep on creating custom tokens and replacing values now that you know where to look. I am not that familiar with the Countries module, but it appears that it is indeed `iso2` based on glancing at this: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/countries/tree/countries.fields.inc

Comment: Thanks for all your help Kevin. I'm still not sure where to look at for the other data.

Comment: Ah, so this is perhaps more involved than I thought, The field will be able to get the `iso2` value, but it looks like Countries are stored as a custom entity. You'd have to load the country by its entity id and inject/concatentate any additional values in the token replacement area. The data actually lives in that Country entity, and not on the node (which just stores the `iso2` value). As I said, I am not that familiar with this particular module, I just happened upon this line and thats how I know it is a custom entity: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/countries/tree/countries.module#n171

Comment: Thanks. I started another discussion regarding getting the meta data from the ISO2: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274692/drupal-countries-programmatically-get-continent-from-iso2

Comment: Gotcha, I will follow up.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to node in this manner into custom token UI:

```
<?php
    //Accessing to node.
    $node = $data['node'];

    //Retrieving your field.
    $token = '[node:your_custom_field_name]';
    $your_field_value = token_replace($token, array('node' => $node));

    // DOing something
    $new_value = ...;

    print $new_value;
?>
```

I hope this help you.