# Programmatically get the continent from ISO2

Tags: 7, tokens

I am using the [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) module to assign countries and associated data to nodes. I am currently writing a custom token and only can access the ISO2 data for the value, not the associated data (full name, language, ISO3).

How can programmatically get the other data with only the ISO2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Continuing the answer from the initial question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274664/using-node-values-in-custom-token), I think you have to load the Country entity to replace the token with what values you are after.

Based on looking at the Countries module, it stores countries as a custom entity:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info().
 */
function countries_entity_info() {
  $return = array(
    'country' => array(
      'label' => t('Country'),
      'plural label' => t('Countries'),
      'entity class' => 'Entity',
      'controller class' => 'EntityAPIControllerExportable',
      'base table' => 'countries_country',
      'token type' => 'country',
      'fieldable' => TRUE,
      'module' => 'countries',
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'cid',
        'name' => 'iso2',
        'label' => 'name',
      ),
      'bundles' => array(
        'country' => array(
          'label' => t('Country'),
          'admin' => array(
            'path' => 'admin/config/regional/countries',
            'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'view modes' => array(
        'full' => array(
          'label' => t('Country'),
          'custom settings' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $return;
}

/**
 * Loads a country entity by ISO alpha-2 code.
 *
 * This is also a menu wildcard loader.
 *
 * @param string $iso2
 *   An ISO alpha-2 string. This is case-insensitive.
 *
 * @return object
 *   A country object loaded by the entity controller.
 */
function country_load($iso2) {
  // The URL's should be case insensitive.
  $iso2 = $iso2 ? drupal_strtoupper($iso2) : $iso2;
  return entity_load_single('country', $iso2);
}
```

It *looks* like the `iso2` value is the entity id, based on this code and the helper load function here, so, you can access the full entity when a token is replaced by:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function MYMODULE_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = [];

  if ($type == 'node' && !empty($data['node']) && array_key_exists('MYTOKEN', $tokens)) {
    $country = country_load($data['node']->field_prgm_country[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['iso2']);
    // $country should be a fully loaded Country entity with all its fields and properties
    // check out $country here with ksm($country);exit;
    $replacements['[node:MYTOKEN]'] = // data you want to show;
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

It looks like the Country module provides its own `country:` scope of tokens, but I do not know how (or if) they work in the context of fields on a node. This should get you closer at least.

Comment: Yes, the country provides some tokens but not working exactly as needed.

Comment: I don't have any project or code setup in front of me, so I can't go too much deeper. But looking at the token_example module of the Drupal Examples module: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/token_example/token_example.module?h=7.x-1.x - once you get the country entity, I think you can work your field with `token_replace('STRING TO AFFECT', ['country' => $country])`. I don't know enough about your project to know what or where, though.

Comment: Thanks kevin. I'm getting close. I've got the continent code printing now but now I need to use a function that is defined elsewhere in a template but is is erroring out since I'm guessing it loads after this.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Function not defined yet.

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: If you have functions defined in templates, like actual `.tpl` files, I would advise moving all of that to a custom module or the theme `template.php` file. Functions should not be defined in `.tpl` files, and can cause issues like this.

Comment: It's a custom function defined in line 1 of template.php via a helper file.

Comment: Its hard to debug this without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The function issue is unrelated to this question anyways.  Where did you find country_load? That was what solved it for me.

Comment: In the Country module itself.